# Why my pizza dough turned out so filling and heavy on the stomach?

Tags: pizza, olive-oil

This is the recipe:

- 1 kg pizza flour
- 680 gr water
- 4 teaspoons dry yeast
- 12 tablespoons olive oil (and even more for handling the sticky dough)
- 2 tablespoons salt & 2 teaspoons sugar
- kneaded for 15 minutes on a stand mixer with a dough hook , than rest for 3 hours.

The pizza turned out beautiful and delicious  with a lot of air pockets in the crust, but was just awful to digest, everyone in my family said that, so its not a personal problem. what should i change to make it more lightweight? Maybe its the ridiculous amount of olive oil that i used? Thank you ;)

Comment: Rolled out how thick, to serve how many? Cooked for how long and at what temperature?

Comment: 250c turbo with an oven stone. Cooked for about 8 minutes until golden brown. thin in the middle and thick crust, about 24cm in diameter.

Comment: How many pizzas did you make from the recipe?

Comment: 2 *tablespoons* of salt for 1kg of flour? Are you sure that's right, or did you get sugar and salt backwards in your question? 2 tbsp of salt would make it inedible.

Comment: @GdD: That seems like a bit of an overreaction. A quick Google search turns up plenty of recipes for pizza dough that use 3% salt by weight, which would equal 30 g in OP's case. Depending on the coarseness of the salt, that could be more or less than 2 tbsp.

Comment: Too much salt could be the reason for stomach discomfort @RubenvanBergen.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote on this, it's a perfectly reasonable and well formulated question, especially from a first time user.

Comment: @GdD: Ruben is right, for a pizza dough you usually use 2-3% (bakers percentages) of salt. This seems to be very much, even excessive, when you compare this to the amount you would use e.g. for a soup. But in fact it does not taste as salty as you would expect when it is incorporated in the dough.

Answer (score 3):

Both the amount of salt and the amount of olive oil in that recipe are on the very high side for a standard pizza dough recipe, so if you found it disagreeable I'd suggest reducing both.  With that amount of olive oil, I'd say that you were making more of a [focaccia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focaccia) than a pizza dough (although focaccia with pizza toppings is generally quite tasty).

Comment: Too much salt can result in a slow to rise dough that can seem heavy.  I sometimes prefer it for empanadas or similar.  And type of salt is significant as table salt packs more densely than flake (kosher) salt

Answer (score 2):

If you have the time and can plan ahead, I've found that leaving pizza dough to ferment in the fridge overnight, around 12 hours or more, makes for a more pleasant and tastier pizza. You may have to cut down on the yeast a little so it doesn't over prove.

**Some observations:** I'm not sure why you are adding sugar. I really don't think pizza dough needs sugar. Also the olive oil does seem to be excessive. Personally I only use a little to oil to grease the bowl so I can get it out of the bowl easily.  A little olive oil in your dough mix can help if you are cooking pizza in a home oven, but I wouldn't go crazy with it. It can help retain a little moisture as you generally need to cook a pizza longer in a home oven (at a lower temperature) than a traditional pizza oven which is much hotter.

If you can, perhaps try to find a traditional Italian pizza dough recipe from a real Italian. They are definitely ***the*** experts when it comes to pizza. If you need to search on youtube "pizza fatta in casa" should get you some authentic recipes.

Comment: Dominoes. They put sugar in their dough, turning what *looks* like a beautiful crust into something nigh-on inedible [unless you like your food sweet, I guess]. Only ever eaten there twice, second time because I couldn't quite believe what I'd had the first time.

Comment: There is no evidence that supports the claim that longer fermentation = better digestion. If you have any data on this, please share.

Comment: @mosacafj I was using that in a colloquial sense, not making a scientific claim. But I've deleted it in case it causes confusion, and replaced it with "more pleasant" - although this is a subjective opinion.

Answer (score -1):

If 1kg of flour, is 8cups and 680 grams of water, is 2.8 cups, it seems to me you do not have enough water to make a correct dough. When I make my rustic bread recipe and use 6 cups of flour I have to use at least 3cups of water. Your recipe is using 8 cups of flour. Another suggestion would be to use unbleached and unbromated flour, like King Arthur, a flour I always use.

Comment: Welcome! Can you explain why unbleached and unbromated flour does as it relates to the question? It's a bit difficult to understand as written :)

Comment: 680 g of water per kg of flour is a normal proportion, quite in the middle of the workable range. Nothing unusual about it. Also, if bleached flour was a reason for inedible bread, nobody would bake with it.